Can't load image from local Flask server to React app
I'm trying to display an image in my react app that I get as a response from a POST request to my local Flask server. I've tried retirieving it both as a bytes array and as a url but nothing worked, firefox's inspector gives me a 'could not load image' when I hover over the element's src...
This is the end of my Flask POST method:
    output.save("path/to/my/outputs/generated.png", "PNG") 

    return send_file("path/to/my/outputs/generated.png", mimetype='image/png') 

src in react reads:
    <img src="data:image/png:base64,iVBORw0KGgo  etc etc

this is my fetch function:
        fetch(
            "http://localhost:5000/path", 
            {
                method: "POST",  
                mode: "cors", 
                body: data
            }
        )
            .then(response => {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                let blob;
                reader.onload = (event) => {
                    blob = new Blob([response as unknown as BlobPart], {type: "image/png"})
                    event.target && setSelfie(event.target.result);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
                }
            })

functional component:
    const [selfie, setSelfie] = useState(placeholderImage)

    return (
        <>
            ........
         
            <img 
                src={selfie}
                alt={placeholderImage}
                width={768}
                height={768}
            >
            
            </img>
        </>
    )

back to Flask, I've also tried:
            with open("path/to/my/outputs/generated.png", "rb") as file:
                saved_img = file.read()
                saved_img_b64 = base64.b64encode(saved_img).decode('utf-8')
                response = {}
                response['data'] = saved_img_b64
                return Response(json.dumps(response))

same thing:
    src="data:image/png:base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAb etc etc     firefox telling me the image could not be loaded

way I handle the fetched response:
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json =>{     
                setSelfie(`data:image/png:base64,${json["data"]};`)
            })

finally I tried a thing I found on stackoverflow where I respond with the bytes array image and just feed the api path to my src:
            with open("path/to/my/outputs/generated.png", "rb") as file:
                saved_img = file.read()
                saved_img_b64 = base64.b64encode(saved_img).decode('utf-8')

                return saved_img_b64

react:
    src="http://localhost:5000/path"     FF could not load image

There's nothing wrong with the images, I can see them just fine in vscode. I'm not getting any content security policy or cors errors, and I when I load placeholder images directly  from the repo to the  element they display fine
Can anyone help?
edit: Running Windows 10 Enterprise

Normally you can server static files directly using any web server like nginx/apache2
you can use this link for refrenece
First setup nginx/apache2 to server static files and then directly in reponse of api send url path, and in frontend use url directly in image tag it should work
it would be good if you share some code will help you in doing that

No problem, but I'm unsure what extra code would help if I posted it ...
I'm still trying to get Apache working, been trying all day, I think I'll take a break and try my luck again tomorrow
